# how to hide file extension on mac os x?

Tags: objective-c, hide, file-extension

say we have a file "a.txt.www". Can I hide abc with objective c? I can hide "a.txt" to "a",and I can also hide "a.abc" to "a", but I can not hide "a.txt.www" to "a.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file only has *one* extension (which can be hidden via the "Hide Extension" checkbox in the Finder's "Get Info" window).

The current version of MacOS and the Finder do not know anything about the concept of multiple file extensions ("`a.txt.www` or "`a.rtf.jet`", where the filename is just "`a`").

Comment: thanks for your reply, I understand a file can only has one extension but I'm wondering how Mac distinguishes filename and extension name? I think it's normal we have a file named "myfile.2010.3.txt", so I don't understand why Mac takes this as a multiple file extensions(myfile + 2013 + 3 + txt?) rather than "(myfile.2013.3 + txt)". If Mac takes this file as "(myfile.2013.3 + txt)" then the file extensions should be able to hidden, if not. then the file name limitation, i think, is not reasonable.

Comment: Although I don't know how Mac distinguishes file extension, I think the reason that System doesn't allow this to happen is due to security issue. it's reasonable, so close it.